# Get max count with lead name

Tags: sql, hiveql

My dataset name bollywood.csv:

[image]
[image]

This is my data. **I need the actors who have the most lead roles in movies.**
I Need the name of the lead actors and the number of films in which they have lead.

My code is:

```
select lead, count(*) as nos from bollywood group by lead order by nos desc;
```

And the result is:

```
Amitabh 3
Akshay  3
John    3
Riteish 2
Shahrukh    2
Sunny   2
Emraan  2
Katrina 2
Nawazuddin  2
Tiger   2
Sharman 2
Manoj   2
Vidya   1
Tusshar 1
Tannishtha  1
Sushant 1
SunnyDeol   1
Sonam   1
Sonakshi    1
Siddarth    1
Shahid  1
Sandeep 1
Salman  1
```

Comment: did you tried top 1 for the result or do you need this result Amitabh 3?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using hiveql or Excel/LibreOffice Calc?

Answer (score 0):

Use rownum pseudocolumn with order by (oracle).

```
select from (
  select lead, count(*) as nos
  from bollywood
  group by lead
  order by lead desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all actors with most lead roles  (possibly multiple records):

```
    select lead, count(*) as nos
       from bollywood
         group by lead
           having count(*) = 
             (select max(cnt) from
               (select lead, count(*) cnt 
                 from bollywood 
                    group by lead ) tblBolly )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select lead, cnt
from (select lead, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
      from bollywood
      group by lead
     ) b
where rnk = 1;
```